# ModuleNotFoundError in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a PyCharm project organized as follows:

---project folder
-----------utilities
-----------------file.py
-----------------file2.py
-----------work
-----------------main.py

in `main.py` I'm using some functions from the utilities package as follows:

`from utilities.file import function, another_function`

in PyCharm I can run it and it works. 
 When I run it on the terminal I hit

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "work\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    from utilities.file import function
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utilities'
```

Someone knows why and how to fix it?

Comment: utilities is not in the same folder as main.py

Comment: Either put your project folder into your python path or use a try-except clause for your imports.

Comment: create an empty file called `__init__.py` in folder `utilities` and try again see if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the terminal, The Python interpreter needs to know to path to your imported module.

Try this

```
import sys
sys.path.append('my/path/to/myModule/dir')
import myModule
```

However, a better approach would be setting PYTHONPATH to your project directory like this

```
set PYTHONPATH=my/path/to/project
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `from ..utilities.file import function, another_function` instead

Explanation: double dots will go up by one directory, and then you will access `utilities` folder, and then you will import `file`

Also, create an empty file named `__init__.py` as recommended by my colleague. Please notice the double underscore.

Comment: `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package` I get this

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import os
mydir = os.getcwd() # directory that your python file
sys.path.append(mydir)
import myModule
```