# File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'x'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, pipfile

***EDIT***

I'm trying to import `algosec.models` in a file inside the `algobot` package.

I've tried to add `--hidden-import algosec`, I've also tried to add the path before importing, using `sys.path.append(./../algosec)`
this is the error message I get when I try to run the program:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "algobot_packer/algobot.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "algobot/cli/cli.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "algobot/microsoft_teams/mainloop.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "algobot/framework/configuration.py", line 34, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "algobot/framework/commands.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "algobot/framework/bot.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "algobot/framework/responses.py", line 9, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'algosec'
```

the folder structure is:

- algobot

  - algobot
  - algosec
  - algobot-packer
  - pyucwa

I'm using `pyinstaller` version `4.2`
I didn't make any change in the code since the last time my executable file ran perfectly fine, but now I'm getting this error every time.
the thing is - the folder 'algosec' is a subdirectory in my project, and it is noted in the pipfile and again, I didn't make any change in a while and tested it recently (last tested on July 8th)),
therefore I believe that it's a dependency issue but not sure which or how to solve.

I've tried multiple changes that somehow worked on one run but when I tried to make these changes again it failed on other builds...

Comment: Here is my question maybe could help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57721990/modulenotfounderror-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently since I took the highest version of `zeep` and `deprecated` without giving a fixed version, it caused issues because of a newer release.
I had to add them to `setup.py` of the `algobot` package which is the main package of the executable with a fixed version.

In addition I had to add a `.egg` file of the `algosec` package with `--paths` in order for pyinstaller to find it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use
`--add-data "path_to_algobot:."` 
based on your system for `windows` use `;` and for `linux` use `:`

It will explicitly add your algosec folder into the package.

Comment: by `path_to_algobot` you mean the path to the project folder? (the one that contains the 4 subfolders?) also, by `:.` the dot stands for destination. can you explaing what is the meaning of src/dest here? I've tried several things that didn't work. it's being built on docker inside a pipenv environment.

Comment: also, do you have any idea why this is happening in the first place?

Comment: `path_to_algobot` means `path_to_missing_file` . `src` here stands for the source of the missing file that means from where to copy it and `dest` is for where to put that file inside the bundle. Yes, the `.` stands for destination you can also put your path instead of `.`. As you haven't shared much of your  code. But from my experience its due to pyinstaller not able to find those files while packaging the bundle.

Comment: seems like after finding the correct combination of paths, and using the `--add-data` flag, I'm getting another `ModuleNotFoundError` for `zeep` package that I'm using. It's in the setup.py and should be imported (worked before) any clue?

Comment: @Daniel It's an quite common issue with pyinstaller. You just have to keep on adding the missing file using `--add-data` and missing imports/modules using `--hidden-imports`. I'm using pyinstaller since long all, I do is keep repeating the above steps till the bundle gets working.

Comment: how would you use `--add-data` on a remote package such as `zeep` that I'm installing from pypi?